# Is it possible to do an efficient and partial search of std::map via std::upper_bound?

Tags: c++, dictionary, find, std

I have a `std::map` and two keys `key_small, key_big` for which I compute the `upper_bound`. It is known that `key_small <= key_big`. Here is how I currently do it:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  // Some example data
  std::map<int, char> data{{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {4, 'c'}, {5, 'd'}, {5, 'e'}};
  int key_small = 1,
      key_big = 3; // key_small <= key_big is always true

  auto it_1 = data.upper_bound(key_big);
  auto it_2 = data.upper_bound(key_small);

  // Do something with it_1, then do something with it_2
}
```

I would like to compute `it_1` and `it_2` in a more efficient manner. The computation of `it_2` above does not take advantage of the fact that I have computed `it_1` already. It searches the whole `map` a second time. My attempt to remedy this is to do the following:

```js
auto it_2 = (it_1 == data.end())
                    ? data.upper_bound(key_small)
                    : std::upper_bound(data.begin(), std::next(it_1), key_small);
```

The second call seems to ignore the underlying data structure. Thus, it is also inefficient.

Is there a better way of computing `it_2`? It appears to me that finding the second iterator should be possible using `log(std::distance(data.begin(), it_1)` comparisons. I was told it's possible in a job interview.

I don't care if the solution is only available in c++20. I also accept solutions specific to libstdc++ or libc++. It would be nice if the solution worked with `find` as well.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to find.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make one call specifying multiple keys, and get resulting upper bound iterators for each. Maybe implementation could make smarter guesses versus what it does for n separate binary (albeit progressively smaller) searches.

Comment: @WilliamClements Yes, this is my idea, but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Can you specify which part is unclear? I am just trying to do compute `it_1` and `it_2`, but in a more efficient manner.

Comment: @SolomonJacobs Your code snippet before updating did not have a sense.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow But is there something else I should improve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you were told it's possible **with standard library containers**, then that person was wrong. If you write your own `map` type, its possible, and in fact, quite trivial for typical tree-like implementations of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do an efficient and partial search of std::map via std::upper_bound?

Although `std::upper_bound` can be used with non-random access iterators, it has linear complexity with those iterators. So, yes it is possible to do it but whether such linear search is efficient depends on the particular case, and in worst case it will be slower than two `std::map::upper_bound` lookups.

If `distance(it_1, it_2) < log2(N)`, then it may be more efficient.

> Is there a way to reap the benefits for both ways of computing it_2?

The interface doesn't provide such algorithm. I don't think that any algorithm could have asymptotically better worst case than the two lookups.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm, I guess I thought wrong.

Comment: Ok, this seems like the correct answer, but I am still hoping that somebody could explain, why the interface does not provide such an algorithm. Maybe it's impossible because of the way black-and-red trees work?

Comment: @SolomonJacobs The thing about computer science is that it is extremely hard to answer the question: "Is the known algorithm optimal, or does a better one exist". Unless you first prove that a better algorithm exists, it is pointless to ask why there is no interface to use such algorithm.

Comment: "asymptotically better worst case" - indeed, the asymptotic behavior is the same, but such an algorithm as the OP is looking for is certainly faster by a constant factor.